# Async/Await function gets called twice

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I made a simple Async function and wanted to test run it in my react app. The function is:

```
async function WAIT(time: any) {
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, time))
}

export async function GetMemberList(orgId: string):Promise<ResponseInterface>{
  await WAIT(3000);
  return {code: 404, data: "Data"}
}
```

And i try to call it in my main app like this:

```
function App() {
  async function fn() {
    let x = await GetMemberList('SOme');
    console.log(x);
  }
  fn();
  return (<div>.....<div>)
}
```

But the problem is `console.log(x)` runs twice. I get {code: 404, data: "Data"} twice. Why is that? Thanks

Comment: A react component will get called every time a component updates. That can be many times. Ideally you would call it inside a `useEffect` so it's only called when the relavent data actually needs to update.

Comment: Have a `useEffect`, use `[]` as the second parameter to call one time, use `[propItDependsOn1, propItDependsOn2]` to trigger a re-run on prop changes. *in* that `useEffect`, set state with the data from the API call (or whatever). Handle not having the data as well as having the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your code and it's outputting once.

Most probably, the problem is that something is triggering a rerender in your template and the `fn()` is getting called again.

You can easily verify it by wrapping your `fn()` inside of a `useEffect()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution:

```
function App() {
  async function fn() {
    let x = await GetMemberList('SOme');
    console.log(x);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fn();
  }, []);

  return (<div>.....<div>)
}
```

Making use of `useEffect` with an empty dependency array will make it so that the `fn()` only gets called once upon the `App` component mounting.

Answer (score 0):

By calling fn() directly in your component, it will trigger every time your component renders. This can happen for many reasons.

You can avoid this with useEffect, and specify the dependencies of the function. In this case, it's only the function itself.

```
function App() {
  async function fn() {
    let x = await GetMemberList('SOme');
    console.log(x);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fn();
  }, [fn]);
  return (<div>.....<div>)
```

However, since fn is redefined every time the component renders, it would still be called every time.

In this specific case, you should define the function outside of the component. It doesn't depend on any data provided by the component, so it's basically a static function. It will never change. In this case, you can safely remove fn from the dependency array

```
async function fn() {
  let x = await GetMemberList('SOme');
  console.log(x);
}

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fn();
  }, []);
  return (<div>.....<div>)
```

There are other ways to do this too. You can define the fn function inside the useEffect, and you can define it with useCallback, so that it will have a stable reference between renders.

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fn() {
      let x = await GetMemberList('SOme');
      console.log(x);
    }
    fn();
  }, []);
  return (<div>.....<div>)
```

With useCallback:

```
function App() {
  const cb = useCallback(async() => {
    let x = await GetMemberList('SOme');
    console.log(x);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    cb();
  }, [cb]);
  return (<div>.....<div>)
```